# using a "defined function" to plot a graph on python

Tags: python, matplotlib, yfinance

assignment question is as follows:

""Use the `make_graph` function to graph the Tesla Stock Data, also provide a title for the graph. The structure to call the `make_graph` function is `make_graph(tesla_data, tesla_revenue, 'Tesla')`. Note the graph will only show data upto June 2021.""

the function is as follows

""

```
def make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=("Historical Share Price", "Historical Revenue"), vertical_spacing = .3)
    stock_data_specific = stock_data[stock_data.Date <= '2021--06-14']
    revenue_data_specific = revenue_data[revenue_data.Date <= '2021-04-30']
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(stock_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=stock_data_specific.Close.astype("float"), name="Share Price"), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(revenue_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=revenue_data_specific.Revenue.astype("float"), name="Revenue"), row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price ($US)", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Revenue ($US Millions)", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
    height=900,
    title=stock,
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
    fig.show()
```

"""
this is my written code:

Tesla_Stock_Graph = make_graph(tesla_data, tesla_revenue, 'Tesla')
Tesla_Stock_Graph()

the below is the "value error i keep encountering

""

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/wsuser/ipykernel_164/231136417.py in <module>
----> 1 Tesla_Stock_Graph = make_graph(tesla_data, tesla_revenue, 'Tesla')
      2 Tesla_Stock_Graph()

/tmp/wsuser/ipykernel_164/2068038883.py in make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock)
     13     title=stock,
     14     xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
---> 15     fig.show()

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3396         import plotly.io as pio
   3397 
-> 3398         return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3399 
   3400     def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py in show(fig, renderer, validate, **kwargs)
    395 
    396         if not nbformat or LooseVersion(nbformat.__version__) < LooseVersion("4.2.0"):
--> 397             raise ValueError(
    398                 "Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed"
    399             )

ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed
```

"""

its meant to plot a "revenue" to "date" graph. by calling be pre defined function "make_graph"
help me

Comment: Did you read the error message? `Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed`

Comment: i did, makes no sense as i've already installed as my first line of codes

Answer (score 0):

The error shows `nbformat` is not installed. Try to install it using pip as follows:

```
pip install nbformat
```

Resoure [LINK](https://pypi.org/project/nbformat/)

Comment: it was installed "!pip install nbformat==4.2.0"